# How can I bridge multiple interfaces to a single one a Cisco ISR C891F but making each one able to communicate only to the destination interface?

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-ios, bridge, cisco-isr

As the question says:

How can I bridge multiple interfaces to a single one on a Cisco ISR C891F, but making each one able to communicate only to the destination interface?

Let's say I have GigabitEthernet0 to GigabitEthernet7.

How can I bridge the range GE1-GE7 to GE0 and make each interface only able to communicate with GE0 and not between each other?

*Cisco IOS Software, C800 Software (C800-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.3(3)M6, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those interfaces are bridged (communicating at layer-2) because they are part of the switch module in the router. It sounds like you want to use a Private VLAN. Cisco has documents that describe this. For example, [*Catalyst 3560 Software Configuration Guide, Release 12.2(52)SE*](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3560/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3560scg/swpvlan.html):

> Private VLANs provide Layer 2 isolation between ports within the same
>   private VLAN. Private-VLAN ports are access ports that are one of
>   these types:
>
> - Promiscuous—A promiscuous port belongs to the primary VLAN and can    communicate with all interfaces, including the community and isolated 
>     host ports that belong to the secondary VLANs associated with the
>     primary VLAN.
> - Isolated—An isolated port is a host port that belongs to an isolated    secondary VLAN. It has complete Layer 2 separation from
>     other ports    within the same private VLAN, except for the
>     promiscuous ports.    Private VLANs block all traffic to isolated
>     ports except traffic from    promiscuous ports. Traffic received from
>     an isolated port is    forwarded only to promiscuous ports.
> - Community—A community port is a host port that belongs to a community    secondary VLAN. Community ports communicate with other
>     ports in the    same community VLAN and with promiscuous ports. These
>     interfaces are    isolated at Layer 2 from all other interfaces in
>     other communities    and from isolated ports within their private
>     VLAN.

Configure a private VLAN with all the interfaces as Isolated, except GigabitEthernet0 that you will configure as Promiscuous.

The problem may be that your switch module in a router may not support private VLANs. The switch modules in routers don't always support all the features of a stand-alone switch.

Comment: Just tested it and I'm afraid "switchport mode private-vlan" is not available on my router, do you know another possible solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the Cisco solution. Did you create the private VLAN first? You must set up the VLANs before you can assign the interfaces.

Comment: Yes, I currently have two VLANs.

Comment: @GamerJota, also be sure to read the limitations. For example, you will need to disable VTP, DTP, etc.. Did you create the VLANs as private VLANs, e.g. `private-vlan isolated`?

Comment: Apparently `private-vlan` is not supported as it says `Invalid input detected` :(

Comment: I know that many of the switch modules in the routers do not support things like ether-channel, or other features that you may expect stand-alone switches to support. You may need to get a stand-alone switch to do this.